# Awesome WM - How to Prevent freerdp from grabbing keyboard in fullscreen mode?

Tags: awesome-wm

I made a dock to start several programms. It appears when the mouse touches the screen border.
When I use xfreerdp in multimonitor mode xfreerdp will automaticaly open in fullscreen mode and grabs the keyboard.

After that, I start e.g. firefox from my dock, however I can´t use the keyboard, because xfreerdp doesn`t release it.

At the moment I use a workarround and minimize xfreerdp when it is in fullscreen mode and looses the focus.

However I wonder if is not possible for awesome to force xfreerdp to release the keyboard?

Thanks in advance.

PS. The xfreerdp "Right-Ctrl ungrab feature" doesn't work for me.

Comment: Just having same problem on i3wm looks like it's generally problem for tiling window managers. Hope there is a solution